# How to copy wt files from another mongo instance?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger, mongodb-atlas

I received a copy of mongo dbpath directory copy from a peer. I copied entire content to my local dbpath with an intention to work on the collections. However, my local is not recognizing the databases or the collections. Am I missing anything?

Comment: We'll need more information to be able to provide suggestions. Did you stop your destination MongoDB server before copying files into the `dbPath`? Was your local `dbPath` empty before you copied the content of the backup? What are the source and destination versions of MongoDB server (x.y.z)? Were there any relevant messages or warnings when you started the destination MongoDB server?

Answer (score 3):

The `WiredTiger.wt` file is a crucial metadata file that keeps track of the state of the whole database and all the `*.wt` files. Hence, the content of this file is deployment specific, and not transferable to other deployments. It is not possible to recreate the content of this file.

If you have a known good backup of the whole `dbpath`, you may be able to restore to a valid state of the database, as long as you restore the `dbpath` as a whole.

Please see [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) for instructions and information on supported backup and restore methods.

For further your ref [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/1hOjNXxTqAY), [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/#db.copyDatabase) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/)