# How to restore from .wt files?

Tags: mongodb, windows

*Environment*
Windows Professional 10
MongoDB 3.6.4 2008R2Plus SSL (64 bit)  `(before computer crash)`
MongoDB 4.0.2 2008R2Plus SSL (64 bit)  `(after computer crash)`

I have been developing locally, and turned on computer today to blue screen of death.

I had no option but to reset Windows 10 and keep personal files.

I therefore have this directory:

`C: > data`

which contains two directories, `db` and `log`.

Below is contents of directory `db`:

[image]

Below is contents of directory `log`:

[image]

I have downloaded and installed:

MongoDB 4.0.2 2008R2Plus SSL (64 bit)

and I accepted the default installation directories:

[image]

**Question**

How can I restore the databases and collections from the contents of my original mongoDB `data` directory?

Note - I am on the same computer, after a Windows 10 reset, and new install of MongoDB.

**Related Questions**

There are similar questions below, but they don't seem to provide an authoritative and accepted answer:

[How to restore .wt backup file to local MongoDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204480)

[How to copy wt files from another mongo instance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204752)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/37557319

https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551549

Answer (score 2):

Some sort of benevolent magic occurred after doing the following:

Remove MongoDB Community Edition as a Windows Service, see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#remove-mdb-edition-as-a-windows-service).

```
sc.exe delete MongoDB
```

Then when I went into my favourite MongoDB GUI ([Robo3T](https://robomongo.org/)), the databases were just there!

So i ran:

```
mongodump
```

To get a "proper" dump of all my databases.

I'm confused how this could happen because the databases are still at their original location:

`C:\data\`

And the new MongoDB installation `data` location was:

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data\`

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Atleast I have a proper `mongodump` backup now.

Comment: Its not working for me, please can help me in this,
I dont get removing as service than how your Robo3T got connected to mongodb